# i want to give permissions to staffuser to create post. any help would be appreciated

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Whenever I testing this code, it's showing that:

> "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

views.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsStaffUser(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_staff


class ProductCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DemoAppProductCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [ IsStaffUser, ]
```

Comment: What is the value of **`authentication_classes`** in your case?

Comment: ohh! i forgot to provide authentication_classes  in ProductCreateAPIView . thanks for your help. really much appreciated.